unable to trigger jenkins jobs through code commit
I have a CodeCommit repository with multiple subfolders, and I have set up a build trigger for it via sns and sqs. However, when I make changes in one of the subfolders, it's not triggering the expected job, but instead triggering another job.
I created trigger job in codecommit with sns.

You might want to give more details. What were the settings for the trigger you created? What's the action that got triggered instead and what trigger did that one have?

I had created trigger in AWS code commit with selecting SNS. Setting is like whenever any commit done in any sub repo it will trigger my Jenkins job. But the problem is its not triggering the job which I am expecting rather than it's triggering any random job of sub repo.
